Probability of Correct Color Matching in a Random Distribution of Balls and Boxes
Problem Statement
A factory produces boxes that are either red or black, with 90% of them being red. In an urn, there are 10 balls, 7 of which are red and 3 of which are black. We independently draw 8 boxes from the production line. In the dark, we draw a ball from the urn and place it in one of the 8 boxes. Afterward, we set this box aside and draw another ball from the urn, placing it in one of the remaining 7 boxes, and so on until the 8th draw. What is the probability that each box contains a ball of the same color as the box?
Here is my attempt at solving the problem
Let $X$ be the random variable representing the number of black boxes among the 8 boxes drawn. $X$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n = 8$ and $p = 0.1$:
$$ P(X = k) = \binom{8}{k} (0.1)^k (0.9)^{8-k} $$
Given $k$ black boxes and $8 - k$ red boxes, we need to find the probability that $k$ black balls are assigned to the $k$ black boxes and $8 - k$ red balls are assigned to the $8 - k$ red boxes.
For the assignment to be correct:

We need to choose $k$ black balls from the 3 available black balls.
We need to choose $8 - k$ red balls from the 7 available red balls.

I think that the probability we are searching for is
$$ P(\text{Correct Assignment}) =\\ \sum_{k=1}^{3} P(X = k) \cdot P(\text{Correct Assignment} \mid X = k) $$
with
$$ P(\text{Correct Assignment} \mid X = k) = \frac{\binom{3}{k} \binom{7}{8-k}}{\binom{10}{8}} $$

I have deleted my solution as I see that I didn't read the problem correctly.  It matters that you have drawn fewer boxes than balls, as now the order of the balls makes a difference (it wouldn't matter if you had the same number).  For instance, it helps a lot if the seven red balls all appear in the first $8$.  Of course, the same approach I used will work here, you just need to consider the possible number of black balls in the first eight.

And I have posted a new solution based on what I hope is a correct reading of the problem.  In that one, I described my interpretation so, if it is incorrect, it should be easy to spot the error or ambiguity.

Note:  I deleted a prior "solution" to this problem after realizing that I had misread the question.  To avoid doubt, here is my interpretation of the question (which still might be incorrect):  You start with $7$ red balls and $3$ black.  You then pair $8$ of these (selected uniformly at random) with boxes (which are selected independently at random) and ask for the probability that all the balls are in boxes of the correct color.
Suppose the balls are lined up.  As we only have eight boxes, we only care about the first $8$ of the balls.  As it is easier to match red balls to boxes, it matters how many black balls are in the first $8$.  Of course that number, $b$ must be one of $\{1,2,3\}$.  We compute the probability of there being exactly $b$ black balls in the first $8$ as $$p_b=\binom 3b\times \binom 7{8-b}\big /\binom {10}8$$
Thus
$$p_1=\frac 1{15}\quad \&\quad p_2=p_3=\frac 7{15}$$
Now, if there are exactly $b$ black balls in the first $8$, the probability that each ball is matched to a box of the right color is $\psi_b=(.9)^{8-b}\times (.1)^b$.  Thus the answer is $$\sum_{b=1}^3 p_b\times \psi_b=\frac 1{15}\times (.9)^7\times (.1)+\frac 7{15}\times ((.9)^6\times (.1)^2+(.9)^5\times (.1)^3)$$  which resolves to $$\frac {2972133}{500000000}=0.005944266$$

Is my approach correct? If so, I should find the same thing as you.

I don't understand your approach.    Why keep track of $k$? If you don't have exactly $7$ red and $3$ black boxes, then the trial is sure to fail.  If you like, you can first compute the probability that you got the right color distribution among the boxes, and then compute the probability that you line them up properly.

Note:  I deleted an earlier version of this solution as I realized I had misread the problem (the prior comments both refer to the incorrect reading).  I am still not sure my interpretation of the problem is the correct one, so I have added my interpretation to the solution.

I find the problem quite challenging, especially in terms of how to interpret it correctly.

Right, so look over my interpretation first.  Make sure that it is what you intended.  As I say, I'm not certain I have it right, though I think my version makes sense and that the solution I described works for it.

As a general matter, I'd suggest simulating as a way to get comfortable with the solution but, here, the probability is so small that accurate simulation will be tough.  Instead, maybe work the problem explicitly for smaller ensembles.  If the numbers were lower, you could just enumerate the possibilities.

Thank you for your help. I will try to understand your interpretation. If anyone else has an interpretation, they can provide it, and I thank them in advance.
